# Prevent disk image automount when clicking Finder sidebar

Tags: macos, dmg, automount

I have been playing around with the **View** → **View Options** in Finder and I must have touched something crtitcal because now whenever I click on a folder in Finder it automounts a disk image located on my external hard drive. The image is located in `/Volumes/elements/App/myapp.dmg`.

If I unplug the external hard drive, everything is back to normal. But when the external  hard drive is connected, it happens again.

I could remove the file, but I want to find a better solution.

**Edit**: It does not matter if I move the dmg to another location (i.e: I move it to `/Users/charasoverride/app.dmg`), it gets automounted as well.

**Update**: It does not happen for every folder but it does for sidebar items. (Favourites, Devices, etc.)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what causes the issue you're describing?

Comment: In finder, i click any folder then the dmg gets automounted, this only happens when my usb disk is connected because the offending dmg is located there, if i remove the usb it does not occur nor get any error.

Comment: So, for example, if you have a `.dmg` file located in `/Volumes/elements/App` and you click on a folder in `~/Desktop`, the `.dmg` mounts itself?

Comment: that's right, but it just happens for that specific dmg, not for all dmgs, i mean i can have more dmg in the folder and they wont get automounted

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that the path you outlined above (/Volumes/elements/App/myapp.dmg) included "elements." This external drive wouldn't happen to be a Western Digital brand drive, would it?

Comment: that's right, it is a western-digital, but i do not think that has nothing to do, if i move the dmg to my hardrive it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying two things. *As a disclaimer, I have no idea what could be causing this because it makes no sense.* These are just some basic Finder troubleshooting steps:

## Suggestion 1:

1. Open Terminal from `/Applications/Utilities`
2. Run the command `killall Finder`
3. Log out of your user account and log back in
4. Try again

## Suggestion 2:

1. Open Finder
2. Navigate to `~/Library/Preferences`
3. Move the files `com.apple.finder.plist` and `com.apple.finder.plist.lockfile` to the Desktop
4. Log out of your user account and log back in
5. Try again

If neither of these suggestions work, I don't know what else you could try. Other StackExchangers?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but none of these worked.

Comment: Update: It does not happens for every folder, only for the items in the sidebar (Favourites / Devices, etc..) it is really anoying because it takes a few seconds until it gets mounted not displaying the folder contents until the dmg is up.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the semi-nuclear options but you could trash the entire contents of ~/Library/Preferences except for perhaps com.apple.mail.* (if you use Apple Mail.app) and com.apple.Safari.* 
Also delete everything in ~/Library/Caches

The full Nuclear option would be to delete almost everything in ~/Library except ~/Library/Mail, ~/Library/Safari, ~/Library/Application Support.

And don't forget to restart after trying those troubleshooting steps.